# "save as" feature not saving light info into world file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I added a custom `Point Light` on Gazebo GUI and save it via `save as` but the resulted `sdf` file only contain `sun` with default setting. I can't either seem to save the default `sun` with modification. Is saving light info not possible yet?

Gazebo 2.2.3 on Ubuntu Trusty 64b

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7452/%22save-as%22-feature-not-saving-light-info-into-world-file/) by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 118 on 2014-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1029/l0g1x/) on 2014-11-17**:
I am also running into same problem. Anyone know answer to this? None of the three light sources save. It might be because they are not technically 'models'?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2014-11-18**:
It seems that this issue has been solved from Gazebo 4.0. I just tried it out on 4.0.2: added some lights with the GUI, changed their colours and poses, and saved the world. When I loaded the world everything was alright.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1029/l0g1x/) on 2014-11-20**:
Do you know if its a seemless upgrade from gazebo 2.2 --> 4.x when involving ros plugins?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-11-24**:
Here is our [changelog](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Changelog.md) and [migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Migration.md).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is fixed in gazebo 4.0.0 (see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/346) for details).

See [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros) for info on using gazebo4 with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0